# mongoengine user with readWrite can not create indexes

Tags: python, mongodb, authentication, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm  running with python 2.7 and mongodb 2.6.5.
I can't get my mongoengine to connect and make request but i can log on mongo with user and make the same request.
I've created 3 users in mongodb like this (password are not blank but i've removed them there):

```
$ mongo campaigns
db.createUser({"user": "admin", "pwd": "", "roles": [
  {"role": "dbOwner", "db":"campaigns" },
  {"role": "dbOwner", "db":"admin" },
  {"role": "readAnyDatabase", "db": "admin" },
   "readWrite" ]},
  { "w": "majority" , "wtimeout": 5000 })

db.createUser({"user": "look", "pwd": "", "roles": ["read"]})
db.createUser({ "user": "write",  "pwd": "", "roles": ["readWrite"]})
```

Then i'm using python and mongoengine to connect to my local mongo (trying with user write and user admin):

```
self.db = connect(setting.DB["db"], "db", host=setting.DB["urli"],
                  port=setting.DB["port"], username=setting.DB["user"],
                  password=setting.DB["pwd"])
```

A print of setting.DB (again pwd is not blank I just don't write it there).

```
{'urli': 'mongodb://localhost/', 'pwd':, 'db': 'campaigns', 'user': 'melu-write', 'port': 27017}
```

There everything is fine, but when i try something like in python:

```
l = [x.name for x in campaign.objects.only("name").all()]
```

MongoEngine give me this error:

```
OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on campaigns.campaigns
```

And When i log from mongo like:

```
mongo campaigns -u write -p
> password:
> db.campaigns.find()
{ "_id":....
```

There is few trace of the error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('createIndexes', u'campaigns'), ('indexes', [{'name': u'offers.product_name_1', 'key': SON([('offers.product_name', 1)]), 'unique': True, 'background': False, 'sparse': False, 'dropDups': False}])])
on namespace campaigns.$cmd failed: not authorized on campaigns to execute command { createIndexes: "campaigns", indexes: [ { name: "offers.product_name_1", key: { offers.product_name: 1 }, unique: true, background: false, sparse: false, dropDups: false } ] }
```

and the same error on the mongo logs:

```
2015-03-05T13:43:33.696+0000 [conn14] Unauthorized not authorized on campaigns to execute command { createIndexes: "campaigns", indexes: [ { name: "offers.product_name_1", key: { offers.product_name: 1 }, unique: true, background: false, sparse: false, dropDups: false } ] }
```

Do you have ideas on what's going on, Why my user with readWrite role can not do a simple findAll, why can't i writes indexes ?
(And why the HELL we need to write indexes to make a simple find query ?)

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what the values are of the arguments to `connect`? Also, is the password really blank? Probably not a problem, but I would try things with a non-empty password.

Comment: @wdberkeley I just don't write password there but there is a password don't worry, and i added the information you asked.

Comment: I think this is a mongoengine problem where mongoengine is ensuring the existence of indexes based on your schemas (does mongoengine have those? not so familiar with it...) but your user is not privileged to create indexes. You'll need to up the privileges for the user or drop mongoengine, or perhaps upgrade if mongoengine has changed in this area.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it was not the roles the caused, but the authenticate method on the db  that was never call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the trouble after posting on the bugtracker of pymongo.

The version i used was not up to date, but worst, mongoengine doesn't authenticate correctly to db.
don't authenticate at connect like i did but rathen do something like this:

```
db = connect("magic", "alias", host="my.url.com", port=port)
db["magic"].authenticate("user", password="pwd")
```

You could try to give this info in the urli but I'think mongoengine is going to used them badly.

Thanks for everything.

Comment: In new version of Celery, there is a bug when database name not set from URI. To fix this you must set it in CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {"database": "your_database"}

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug of mongoengine connect auth. It seem to have solved it by doing

```
client = connect(<db_name>, host='mongodb://<host1>:<port 1>,<host 2>:<port 2>/<db name>', username="<username>", password="<password>", authentication_source="<auth db name>", replicaSet="<rs name>" )
client.admin.authenticate("<username>", "<password>")
```

An explanation as to why this fixed the issue would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone:

Is this by chance the first operation you are trying to do on the mongo database?
Perhaps your username/password is not configured correctly? With mongo, if you haven't authenticated correctly, you can connect without authenticating and you won't get an error until you perform an operation that requires authentication.